# Do loop with 2 variables changing in each step of loop

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I'm working on Fortran 90. I need to calculate a recursion like xn = 6*(xn-1) + 7*(xn-2) where (xn-1) is the n-1 step and (xn-2) is the n-2 step. So if we set x1 = 2 and x0 = 1 we get x2 = 6*x1 + 7*x0 and so on for each n.

So I wrote

```
x0 = 1.
x1 = 2.
do i = 1,20
   xn = 6.*x1 + 7.*x0
   x1 = xn
   x0 = x1
end do
```

but this code is replacing x0 and x1 for xn and I need to replace x1 for xn and x0 for x1 in each step. I'd tryed many things but I failed. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Flip the order of those two assignments. So, assign to x0 first, then assign to x1.

Answer (score 3):

Though the answer has already been added to this question, let me answer a more general question which is encountered more frequently. Consider the problem where the very next value in the iteration depends on `n` previous values. In the present case `n = 2`. The general strategy to solve this problem is to construct another 1-d array of size `n` and save all the initial values `x(1),x(2),..,x(n)` in this array. Then in each iteration we use these values to calculate the next value  `x(n+1)` and update the array with `x(1) by x(2), x(2) by x(3),...,x(n) by x(n+1)` and again use these values to calculate the next value of `x` and so on. A particular example where such strategy must necessarily be used is the integration of time-delayed systems.

Comment: To update the array in this general problem, the intrinsic functions `cshift` and `eoshift` are quite useful.

Answer (score 2):

@parthian-shot has given the correct answer in the comment. But that leaves the question marked as unanswered, so I am repeating it here:

You are assigning the value of `xn` to `x1`, and then the value of `x1` (which is now the same as `xn`) to `x0`. You just need to flip it around:

```
do i = 1,20
   xn = 6.*x1 + 7.*x0
   x0 = x1
   x1 = xn
end do
```